# TFS - list with Missing files

Tags: tfs

Let's consider this scenarion: In case that I sinchronize my local folder with latest version at Team Foundation Server 2010 and after that manually delete some local file. My question is how I can force TFS to show me Missing files? (Source Safe would show Missing files in this case) For now, TFS check only file versions (not data) and if there is no change it doesn't make any other actions. In this case there is no version change and it doesn't recognize need for action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can perform a get specific version and check the option to download all files even if they match (second option).

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181387.aspx for more information.

Answer (score 3):

Good advice from Robaticus, you can also use the [TFS power tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f/). You'll need to select a cutom install and make sure that explorer integration is checked.

This will add a new item to your context menu in windows explorer called "Team Foundation Server" you can use this to get latest, move and delete files. This will save the hastle of opening up Visual Studio when you just want to make a simple edit or delete.

Comment: Thank you very much for this useful tools! This will help us to get out of the habit of using the source control and Windows Explorer to manipulate files. Could you please inform me, where I can find more details, documentation, best practices,... for TFS Power Tools because I found it as very useful, but at main link there is no so much information?

Comment: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z51z7zy0%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is a link to the help for the tfpt command line tools and I'd suggest reading the blogs of Brian Harry, Buck Hodges, Bill Heys and Jim Lamb (amongst many others). If you go to [Buck Hodges's blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/) and look on the right hand side you'll see "Blog - Link List" All of the TFS teams blogs are compulsory reading, there is a lot of very useful information.

Answer (score 2):

Get out of the habit of using the file system and Windows Explorer to manipulate files. Use the Source Code Explorer to delete them.  Otherwise you'll run into problems in the long run.